# Issues with Google+ sign in

Tags: android, google-plus, google-plus-signin, android-googleapiclient

I am having trouble with google+ sign in,
here is my googleApiClientBuilder

I have succeeded in logging in once after 15-20 attempts but after that no issue it's alway going in else of `if (result.isSuccess())`

I have connected to googleApi on Start

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN.toString()))
            .requestEmail()
            .requestId()
            .requestProfile()
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
    SignInButton googlePlusSignInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.act_reg_gpsi_login);
    if (googlePlusSignInButton != null) {

        googlePlusSignInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
        googlePlusSignInButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
```

Sign in Handles

```
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = result.getSignInAccount();
        if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
            pdLoginWithSocialMedia = UIUtility.createProgressDialog(this, "Please wait", "Logging in");
            performSocialLogin(LoginFrom.GOOGLE_PLUS,
                    googleSignInAccount.getId(),
                    googleSignInAccount.getDisplayName(),
                    (googleSignInAccount.getPhotoUrl() != null) ? googleSignInAccount.getPhotoUrl().toString() : "",
                    (googleSignInAccount.getPhotoUrl() != null) ? googleSignInAccount.getPhotoUrl().toString() : "",
                    googleSignInAccount.getEmail(),
                    "",
                    2);
        } else {
            showSignUpLoginIssue(ErrorIssue.ERR_UNKNOWN);
        }
//            updateUI(true);
    } else {
        showSignUpLoginIssue(ErrorIssue.ERR_UNKNOWN);
    }
}
```

StartActivity to handle Response

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        int statusCode = result.getStatus().getStatusCode();
        } else {
            showSignUpLoginIssue(ErrorIssue.ERR_UNKNOWN);
        }
    } else {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you log what status is returned from the sign in attempt using:  `Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data).getStatus()`. If it returns a DEVELOPER_ERROR status maybe your project configuration is incorrect. Check if the google_services.json in your main project folder contains all the required client ids. Refer to this page https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating for the required configuration.

Comment: @VeselinTodorov it is returning 10

Comment: Well as you can see here https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes status code 10 means DEVELOPER_ERROR so your configuration is probably incomplete. You must configure your project in the developer console.

Comment: @VeselinTodorov thanks man, it was configuration issue